# What is cell neighborhood size in gdaldem?

Tags: gdal, gdaldem

I would like to know the cell neighborhood size used in some of the utilities in gdaldem. I can't seem to find them in the documentation. For example, TRI has per definition 8-cell neighborhood size, but this is not the case for Roughness which should have a user-set size.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: did you look in the code?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! From what I could understand in the source code it seems as if gdaldem operates on a 8-cell neighborhood in all its operations.